# How can I use arguments, when I remote debug a jar on Linux

Tags: java, debugging, parameters, arguments, sh

I created an sh on Linux to run this command:
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4001,suspend=y -jar myjar.jar foo

The main method's parameter is String... args (I tried with an array as well), and I would expect the following value: "foo", but while I'm debugging, the String is empty.

What can be the problem?

Comment: What phenomenon occured for you to know "the String is empty"? And more import, show us the code.

Comment: I used IntelliJ IDEA for debugging and I evaluated the args value, and it was "".

The code:
public class MyClass {
 public static void main(String... args) {
  System.out.println("args: " + args.length + ", " + args.toString());
 }
}

Output: args: 0,

Answer (score 0):

Please try to debug the code by printing expected outputs:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
     String foo = args[0];
  }
  catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    System.out.println("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException caught");
  }
}
```